# PHP issue using fgetcsv and then foreach

Tags: php, foreach, fgetcsv

Ok, here's the thing.

```
if (!$fp=fopen($file,"r")) echo "The file could not be opened.<br/>";  
            while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 1000 , ',')) !== FALSE ) {
                // here, var_dump($data); shows the correct array
                $i = 0; 
                foreach ($data as $i=>$row ) {  
                   $matrix=explode( ',', $row);
                   // $matrix recieves only the first field of the csv line
                   // seems like I'm getting a field on each foreach iteration
                   // shouldn't I get the whole line each time?
                } //end foreach
            } //end while
```

I don't really see the problem here.
By the way, this code works on my local machine, and doesn't work on my server. Both are linux, and php versions are the same.

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Have you got error reporting on?  Do you have the correct permissions to read that file?

Comment: error reporting is on, and I do have correct permissions to read the file. anyway, I get no erros, and I do read the file indeed, but foreach iteration I get a field, when I think I should be getting a line. That's my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter is a comma and not a semicolon (;)? Also you can try setting the limit to 0.

Comment: short lines, and delimited by a comma. tried both, no luck. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgetscv() returns each row as an array.  So your problem is this:

$data is a row, which is already an array.  Each iteration in the while() loop will return a row. There is no need for an explode.

```
$allRowsAsArray = array();
if (!$fp=fopen($file,"r")) echo "The file could not be opened.<br/>";  
while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 1000 , ',')) !== FALSE ) 
{
    $allRowsAsArray[] = $data;
}
print_r($allRowsAsArray); //Will return your entire csv as an array of rows, each row as an array.
```

Comment: Well, it was THAT easy. I don't know what got into me for be trying that wicked code. Thank you so much.